# Access UI from a WebService callback event windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Hi I am developping a Windows phone 8.1 application in VS 2013.

There I am calling a webservice using "HttpWebRequest" which is an async call.

When web service finishes its work and called back to my callback function , there I don't have controll over my UI. Only I have access to my DB. So I am not able to let the user knows that webservice has been completed.

How can access UI elements or a page redirect from webservice calledback event.

The other thing what I have tried is to call Sync method but it is not working.

Any help/Suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Dispatcher.Invoke, which you can use to access the UI. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx